# How do thresholds affect were-forms?

Tags: dresden-files, thresholds

I've read different accounts on how thresholds affect wereforms, and haven't been able to find anything in the rules to clear them up.

From what I've read people seem to imply that they can pass through them just fine, but maybe can't shift once they are passed the threshold (uninvited). As in if they crossed in human form they cannot become an animal-form or if they cross in animal-form they cannot become a human. Is this the case?

Also, any powers they had would suffer a penalty, but nowhere seems to describe what kind. I was thinking maybe it reduces the refresh capable of being used? Like if a were-form has -4 in powers for Inhuman Speed and Inhuman Strength and a threshold they pass uninvited has a +2 strength then maybe they have to lose 2 refresh worth of powers. So either they lose their speed or their strength.  Is this a correct reading?

Comment: Your edits to separate questions were indeed appreciated- but this question is *still* two questions in one.  Each question should be focused on one specific question- both to help you get the best answer, and to be as useful as possible for posterity.  I've edited out the secondary question, though you are welcome to make/rollback the changes I've made.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've made the second question into another post titled "How do thresholds affect true shapeshifters with modular abilities?" and also edited my original post of some.

Comment: This isn't game related but I'm rereading Fool Moon and I can't think of any instance where thresholds are a hindrance to the various were-beings in this book or any of the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dresden Files RPG suggests that thresholds mainly affect beings of pure spirit, and as such, were-beings wouldn't be affected.

Looking at the requirements for were-beings (YS82), it specifies that "the animal in question isn't supercharged or innately magical". The shapeshift itself also isn't specified as magical. I'd also argue that thresholds don't affect something like a Hexenwulf; YS230 mentions that demons can get around thresholds by creating a physical body, and as the demon in the belts only does the 'heavy lifting', the being using the belt is controlling the transformation rather than the demon.

I'd possibly tweak the rules for a being that changes mass (either gaining or losing), as YS83 mentions that they use the NeverNever to store excess mass or gain ectoplasm, and this use could be affected by the threshold. This is (IMO at least) reinforced by the Red Court's inability to cross thresholds - their flesh masks are entirely ectoplasm.

I don't know about the Inhuman abilities; the DFRPG suggests avoiding these if you can give more beast-like abilities instead. I think this would potentially be down to the GM's discretion over threshold powers; maybe if you had a particularly powerful one it would affect the inhuman abilities, but a weak one wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it says anything in the RPG books, but in the second book of the Novels, Fool Moon, Bob explains that the "classic werewolf" (the kind that the Alphas are), is a minor practitioner, who has learned the one spell that changes and rearranges their body to the shape of an single kind of animal they choose, and back again.

Since thresholds block wizards from their magic, I would think that they would prevent a werewolf from shifting inside (assuming of course it hasn't been invited in). However, the spell they use to shift is not one they have to maintain.

They cast the spell when they shift, and again to turn back. When they're in either form, they aren't casting any spells. If they somehow lost their magic when in wolf form, they would probably remain that way for the rest of their life.  Once the spell is done rearranging their body, it doesn't require any more energy to keep it in place.

So, if a wolf was to enter a threshold uninvited, I think they would probably stay a wolf, but until they left or were invited, they would be stuck in that form.